# In this case, how should I access to the JProgressBar from another class?

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I am currently practicing OOP with Java.

I have created a GUI project via WindowBuilder with Eclipse IDE and below is the result.

```
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Example window = new Example();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Example() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

What I am trying to do is to connect the **JProgressBar** to another class that has the actual task, to show the progress.

For example, if the other class contains the following code:

```
int i = 0;
while(i <= 100) {
    progressBar.setValue(i);
    i++;
}
```

how should I change the **progressBar.setValue(i);** part?

Comment: "I am currently practicing OOP with Java." - Doing this with Swing is as if you'd try to learn juggling with 5 flaming sticks. Try the basics first.

Comment: "What I am trying to do is to connect the JProgressBar to another class that has the actual task, to show the progress." - You _could_ just have that other task update the progress bar or you could just send a notification to the progress bar and have it read the data from the tasks model (see the MVC pattern). One important thing though: run the task on a separate thread.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) section.

Here's the simplest working example I could create.  As you can see in the picture, I caught the JProgressBar in the middle.

[image: Example]

Each time you press the button, the progress bar will count from 0 to 100, one unit every 100 milliseconds.

In order to access the progress bar, you have to make it a class field or variable.  You can then access the class field with a setter.  Getters and setters are a basic Java concept.  You can see another example of a plain Java getter/setter class in my `JProgressBarModel` class.

I used a Swing `Timer` to add a delay to the updating of the progress bar so you can see the bar update and simulate an actual long-running task.  The actual work takes place in the `WorkListener` class.  Because the code is inside an `ActionListener`, the Swing update of the progress bar takes place on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JProgressBarExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JProgressBarExample());
    }

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    private final JProgressBarModel model;

    public JProgressBarExample() {
        this.model = new JProgressBarModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Bar Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        panel.add(progressBar);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start Process");
        button.addActionListener(event -> {
            model.setIndex(0);
            setValue();
            Timer timer = new Timer(100, new WorkListener(this, model));
            timer.start();
        });
        panel.add(button);

        return panel;
    }

    public void setValue() {
        progressBar.setValue(model.getIndex());
    }

    public class WorkListener implements ActionListener {

        private final JProgressBarExample view;

        private final JProgressBarModel model;

        public WorkListener(JProgressBarExample view, JProgressBarModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
            int index = model.getIndex() + 1;
            model.setIndex(index);
            view.setValue();
            if (index >= 100) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }

    }

    public class JProgressBarModel {

        private int index;

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do it similar to the frame part. You Example class has a field variable that could be directly accessible to your other code.

A better way would be to have a private field for the JProgressBar and a getProgressBar() method.

But currently you are using a method variable that is forgotten when initialize() returns.